# How to access this type of property?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have Json OUTPUT which has last `highest_value` and i want to print in my ajax:

```
[{"first":1},{"last":1},{"other":3},{"highest_value":{"other":3}}]
```

How can I access `{"highest_value":{"other":3}` **in my ajax**.

Here is my ajax code:

```js
<script>


          $.getJSON('/ytl/public/api/first-hour-trades', function(data) {

              $.each(data, function(firstHourTrades, element) {
                  $("#msg1").append($('<div>', {
                      text: element.first
                  }));
                  $("#msg2").append($('<div>', {
                      text: element.last
                  }));
                  $("#msg3").append($('<div>', {
                      text: element.other
                  }));
                  $("#msg4").append($('<div>', {
                      text: element.highest_value[0]
                  }));
              });
          });




    </script>
```

Comment: element.highest_value.other

Comment: `other` is variable.. means it will change if `first` has higher value.

Comment: one thing, I also tired `text: element.highest_value.other` but this is nothing to result, @rmlan

Comment: `data[3].highest_value`

Comment: You can use `Object.keys()` to extract the keys from `element.highest_value`. If that sub-object always has just one property, then `element.highest_value[Object.keys(element.highest_value)[0]]` will get that value. It's not exactly clear that that's what you're asking for however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `data` is the array you’ve shown, then [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) it:

```
console.log(data
  .find((prop) => prop.hasOwnProperty("highest_value")));
```

That will yield `{"highest_value":{"other":3}}`.

To get `3`, get the first [value of the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) at `.highest_value`:

```
console.log(Object.values(data
  .find((prop) => prop.hasOwnProperty("highest_value"))
  .highest_value)[0]);
```

---

If you alread know that it’s the fourth element, then you don’t need to find it and you could simply use this to put the `3` as `text`.

```
$("#msg4").append($('<div>', {
  text: Object.values(element.highest_value)[0]
}));
```

If you don’t know which element will have the `highest_value` property or how many there will be, you could rewrite your code like this:

```
$.getJSON('/ytl/public/api/first-hour-trades', function(data){
  const highest = data.splice(data.findIndex((prop) => prop.hasOwnProperty("highest_value")), 1)[0];

  data.forEach((element, index) => $(`#msg${index + 1}`).append($('<div>', {
    text: Object.values(element)[0]
  })));
  $(`#msg${data.length + 1}`).append($('<div>', {
    text: Object.values(highest.highest_value)[0]
  }));
});
```

The IDs with increasing numbers may also not be necessary, but it all depends on what the bigger picture is supposed to look like.

Comment: Actually where should I put this. between `$("#msg4").append($('<div>', { #########    }));`?

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati You put the part `Object.values(`…`)[0]` wherever you need the `3`.

Comment: This is giving `syntax`, because i don't where should i put your code in my ajax code.

Comment: I think I should learn more. well think you so much for giving me time. If you think question is good. then thumb up because, its import me to get answer. @X

Comment: I think your answer is perfect because my `highest_value` is variable. but i dont till How to use `your code`.

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati I’ve edited the answer with some code samples that might help you implement my ideas.

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much. @Xufox

Comment: Can you suggest me any book or web, or video tutorial for me to learn this type of `Javascript /AJAX`?

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati Sure, I’d always recommend [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn). This code especially uses [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods_of_the_Object_constructor) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2) methods and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Also note that I’ve replaced the jQuery `each` loop by a native `forEach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Really, it might be best if you could restructure your response:

```
{
    "first":1,
    "last":1,
    "other":3,
    "highest_value":{"other":3}
}
```

in which case you would access it as follows

```
element.highest_value.other
```

if you really can't afford to do that, but you want to make the selection order agnostic (in case the data structure changes over time) you would need to do something like

```
data.forEach(function(obj){
    if(obj.highest_value !== undefined){
        console.log(object.highest_value.other);//this is the one you want
    }
});
```

making a functioning version of your code look something like:

```
$.getJSON('/ytl/public/api/first-hour-trades', function(data) {

    $.each(data, function(firstHourTrades, element) {//this loops once for each object
        if(element.first !== undefined){//we need to check if this is the object with the property "first"
            $("#msg1").append($('<div>', {
                text: element.first
            }));
        }
        if(element.last !== undefined){
            $("#msg2").append($('<div>', {
                text: element.last
            }));
        }
        if(element.other !== undefined){
            $("#msg3").append($('<div>', {
                text: element.other
            }));
        }
        if(element.highest_value !== undefined){
            $("#msg4").append($('<div>', {
                text: element.highest_value.other
            }));
        }
    });
});
```

though I'd really recommend rethinking your data structure as you can imagine that would be quite messy as it grows more complex.

Comment: I suspect you can't depend on the property name of `.highest_value` being `other`. It's presumably the name of whichever other property contains the highest value.

Comment: If you're going to reorganize the data, it would probably be better to have that be `highest_value: {propname: "other", value: 3}`

Comment: @Barmar I think that's likely fair. But I didn't try to speculate as to the intent behind the data, just the provided example. I would recommend this as well in that light

Comment: I will re-organize but right i am learning so, sometime stuck my brain after a lot tired. some people also thumb down my question. lol Thanks so much. @Barmar